# Using HTML Form Inputs to Define URI Path

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I'm looking to create an HTML form that will take the form inputs and dynamically create a URI path.  The page that hosts the form has to be pure HTML.  I've been able to create a form that will pass the inputs to a PHP handler/redirect page, but I've thus far been unable to use the form inputs to define the uri path.

I get a Url that looks like:

`http://www.host.com/beds-$_POST["beds"]/baths-$_POST["baths"]')`

when using POST.  I've tried setting **$_POST["beds"] = $PathVariable** but that hasn't worked either.

GET doesn't seem to be the solution as the uri string isn't object=value and I end up with a string that looks like

```
/beds-$_GET["beds"]/baths-$_GET["baths"]/beds=2baths=2.
```

Does anyone know a way to take only the form input value and use it to change out a specific portion of a url string?  Ideally the user would select # of beds and # of baths from the HTML form and be redirected to a URL like this: https://www.host.com/beds-#/baths-#/.  I've only tried a PHP redirect page.  If anyone knows a way to do this with PHP or another scripting language please advise.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not possible to do what you ask. Forms can submit data either through the body of the request, or via the query string. Any other behavior would need to be handled via JavaScript, or server-side redirects. I suggest learning how to use HTTP requests properly and not attempting this foolish non-standard method that you've devised.

Comment: You say HTML only then you talk about a PHP handler.  That's fine but you should clarify the HTML only page can submit to a PHP file.   Where is the code for your form, or the PHP handler you have now?

Answer (score 0):

Short solutions:

1. Use JavaScript.
2. Use server-side scripts.

HTML forms cannot do this by itself.

Answer (score 0):

The code needed to execute the redirect/use case is below.

```
<?php

$Path1 = $_POST["beds"];
$Path2 = $_POST["baths"];

$endpath = "beds-$Path1/baths-$Path2";
$startpath = "static/path";


$URL="http://host.com/$startpath$endpath";
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="0;URL=' . $URL . '">';
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.location.href='{$URL}';      </script>";

 ?>
```